# mysql ordering by categorizing number range, then alphabetically in individual categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a list of teams that order by their dollars amount column and as PHP posts it on my page, it has a tier/category labeled to each team depending on what tier each teams' amount is.  Example:

SQL result:

```
Team | Amount
  A    550.00
  B    1200.00
  C    320.00
  D    800.00
```

PHP lays out like:

```
B - Top tier (over $1,000)
D - Middle tier (over $500)
A - Middle tier (over $500)
C - Low tier (over $150)
```

Now I have a ton more teams displaying on the page and what I need to do is they are still displaying in order of amount from highest to lowest on the page and I actually need the SQL to output into their tiers and then order alphabetically in each tier.  So for example (using my tiny PHP output example above), the teams "D" and "A" are both in the same tier, but "A" should be displayed first alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Amount > 1000 THEN 4
            WHEN Amount > 500 THEN 3
            WHEN Amount > 150 THEN 2
            ELSE 1
       END Tier,
       Team, Amount
FROM Table
ORDER BY Tier DESC, Team
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select teamname from (
    select teamname, 1 as ordern from teams where Amount>=1000
        union all
    select teamname, 2 from teams where Amount<1000 and Amount>=500
        union all
    select teamname, 3 from teams where Amount<500 and Amount>=150
        union all
    select teamname, 4 from teams where Amount<150
) as q
order by ordern DESC, teamname ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to order first by amount and second by team.

```
select TeamName,'Top tier (over $1,000)'
from table where amount > 1000
union all
select TeamName,'Middle tier (over $500)'
from table where amount between 500 and 1000
union all
select TeamName,'Low tier (over $150)'
from table where amount between 150 and 500
order by 2,1
```

Comment: imagine team A has 1001, but team B has 10002